# Windows Mobile Development on MacBook Pro?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-mobile, hardware, development-environment

I am a frequent Windows Mobile application developer in need of a new development laptop.

I am considering a MacBook or Macbook Pro running either Fusion from VMWare or Parallels Desktop.  This will give me the option to port my applications to the iPhone depending on what MS does with WM 6.5 and 7.

Has anybody tried doing Windows Mobile development using Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center (or ActiveSync) and VS2008 on the MacBook Pro using one of these virtual machines?  Does the device emulator work properly?   What about debugging a Windows Mobile device over a USB cable?

In general, do most USB drivers (non HID) designed for Windows work under these virtual machines?

Answer (score 1):

I do cross platform (iPhone & Windows Mobile) development all the time on a Macbook (13" unibody). Have Visual Studio 2008 running on Windows XP on a Parallels VM. The USB pass through works perfectly for debugging too.

I would suggest you have 4Gb ram (minimum) if doing this, but works very well.

Answer (score 0):

VMware's USB passthrough option works quite well. I have no personal experience using it to attach Windows Mobile devices to a guest OS though.